# Use ProductList widget

Tags: magento2, product-list, widget

I try to display list of products with the widget ProductsList, without success.

I have the following code :

```
$block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList');
$condition = [
   '1' => [
       'type' => \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine::class,
       'aggregator' => 'all',
       'value' => '1',
       'new_child' => '',
   ],
   '1--1' => [
       'type' => \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Product::class,
       'attribute' => 'sku',
       'operator' => '==',
       'value' => 'my_sku',
   ]
];
$conditionEncoded = $this->conditionsHelper->encode($condition); // conditionsHelper = \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions
$block->setConditions($conditionEncoded);
$block->toHtml();
```

Currently, I only try to display 1 sku, but at the end, I want to display a list of sku.
However, `$block->toHtml();` return empty and I din't get any error.

Then, I try to debug :

`$block->toHtml()` call `protected function _beforeToHtml()` in `ProductList.php`.
In this function, we have `$this->setProductCollection($this->createCollection());`
In `createCollection`, I display the `$collection->getSelect()->__toString()`. This request is good and return my sku.
So why nothing is displaying with `->toHtml()` ?

Do you know where can I get a documentation about how to create this `$condition` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it as

```
$block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList');
$condition = [
   '1' => [
       'type' => \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine::class,
       'aggregator' => 'all',
       'value' => '1',
       'new_child' => '',
   ],
   '1--1' => [
       'type' => \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition\Product::class,
       'attribute' => 'sku',
       'operator' => '==',
       'value' => 'my_sku',
   ]
];
$block->setConditions($condition);
$block->toHtml();
```

Note: *No need to encode it for `setConditions()` method*